# not able to decode the params in @GET api

Tags: java, android, api, kotlin, retrofit

trying to send this ?filters=[{"field":"user_id","value":"633a71e6644de2ad5123c57b"}]
but it is not going the way want it is going like this

filters=[{%22field%22:%22user_id%22,%22value%22:%22633a71e6644de2ad5123c57b%22}]  already did the encoded= true

Comment: %22 is the encoded value of double quotes.

Comment: please check you are utf decoding.

Answer (score 0):

In your build.gradle(:app)add below dependency:

```
implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.9'
```

And create your json object like below:

```
    var filters = JSONObject()
    filters.put("field","user_id")
    filters.put("value","633a71e6644de2ad5123c57b")
    System.out.println(filters.toString())
```

This will print the output as you wanted.